# Rails 4 favicon issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, favicon

Trying to add a favicon to my rails app, but doesn't seem to be working locally. Heres my code

Aplication.html.erb (in the head section)

```
<%= favicon_link_tag '/favicon.ico' %>
```

**Note:** Favicon has been saved within my asset/images folder and the icon is 64x64 pixel

Is there anything thats been done wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: this should work if you have `favicon.ico` file in your `public` directory. for me it worked. their was a favicon.ico file already present in public directory, i had to replace that with new favicon.ico.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I think the address should be without the slash:

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
```

Comment: Perfect, No problem :) Please mark the question as answered if it is correct, so other users can benefit :)

Comment: Something else to be sure of is Rails has a default favicon in `public/favicon.ico` - you can replace this if you want to make a "default" icon; you can use this method to declare non-default icons ;)

Comment: I tried placing my favicon.ico file in the public directory on Rails 4 and it didn't work for me. The above solution and placing it in the asset/images folder did though.

Comment: Note this points to `app/assets/images/favicon.ico`, as opposed to `public/assets/images/favicon.ico`

Comment: @benjineer That is not true. Placing it in public/assets/images also works

Comment: **NOTE** Place the favicon.ico image in `/app/assets/images/` **if you are using the asset pipeline**, and in `/public/images/` if you are not.

Answer (score 7):

The proper use of `favicon_link_tag` is the immediate solution:

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
```

However, a single `favicon.ico` can only address most desktop browsers. Mobile browsers can't cope with it but need higher resolution icons, like the Touch icon for iOS devices. You can get support for all browsers with  [RealFaviconGenerator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon/ruby_on_rails):

- Go to [RealFaviconGenerator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon/ruby_on_rails) and submit your picture. You can edit your icons platform-per-platform (Android, iOS...).
- When the icons are ready, follow the instructions.

The instructions are clear enough to setup the favicon, so there will be no path issue, no "extra slash" issue, etc.

Full disclosure: I'm the author of this site.

Answer (score 1):

Using rails 4.2.3, in my `/public` folder there was already a favicon. I simply replaced that and DID NOT ADD `<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>`. Worked perfectly.

Weird thing is I first tried with the `favicon_link_tag` and that somehow *prevented* the favicon from showing up.

Answer (score 0):

The proper use of favicon: 
add this  `<%= favicon_link_tag(source='favicon.ico')%>`

Comment: `source=` does nothing in this line. (other than setting a local variable named `source`.)